# Use Facebook Api Locally

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, localhost

I am attempting to use the facebook api with my php web application. I have downlaoded the api and in my app settings is added a website platform with the Site URL as my localhost address `http://localhost:8080/app/` for testing.

However it does't add to the seetings with this, when I try to save this in the App Dashboard I get an error message, but when I set it as `http://localhost/app/`, it saves it.

I am doing this to sort out the error I get when I try to use the api.

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/app/`, the page redirects to:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=648801771829346&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fkfc%2Ffacebook_connect&state=1e655991943d79a58aac8d22fbd2c61f&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3

with the error:

> Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

My code:

```
<?php
 require_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook= new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '648801771829346',
      'secret' => 'd4a528ad0614314a9d3aaf59c978fbfa',
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($user_profile);
    echo "</pre>";
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
  die('<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>');
}
```

How do I fix this do that I can test locally on `http://localhost:8080/app/`, this is my xampp server.

DashBoard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
First, Add a platform -> Website

Settings -> Basics -> App on Facebook -> Canvas URL -> http://localhost/app?
Settings -> Basics -> Website -> Site URL as http://localhost/app/
```

Comment: Not seeing that option. See image above.

Comment: It save but I still get the redirect and the error. I am testing on localhost:8080, but the  dashboard is not allowing me to save that as my site url

Comment: Actually just fixed it. I had to add it as my "App Domain"

Answer (score 0):

There is a toggle button in the **Settings->Advanced** part of your application which says **"Native or desktop app? Enable if your app is a native or desktop app"**. When you turn on that switch, I think you will be able to send back to localhost the information from Facebook.